# Spotify language settings

Tags: language-support, spotify

i installed Spotify from the Ubuntu Snap Store but it was only installed in English and i cannot change the language to German. The settings point is shown greyed. I also tried to install it from the Spotify page but it was also installed in English.

Has anybody a solution?

greetings

Mathias

Comment: I have the Spotify snap and can select between quite a few display languages. Possibly it helps that I have a Spotify account...

Comment: Okay i also have a Spotify account but i can't select....the field is Show greyed

Comment: Has anybody a helpful solution?